# How can I tell when a user moves from one section to another in a webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When a user moves from one page to another, I have a line of Javascript that highlights on the sidebar menu where they are at. I have a couple menu items that link to content on the same webpage though and I'd like to automatically update the menu as the user scrolls up or down to be on the menu item that correlates to the part of the page they are on.

Is there a way to do this based on my anchor tags?

EDIT:

These anchor tags:

```
<a name="Section1"></a>
<a name="Section2"></a>
```

Comment: Hi we cant see `Code` here!

Comment: You mean the anchor tags provided in your question? Because there are none.

Comment: Man, you guys are ruthless.

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com That's because there wasn't any. But I  added some examples of what anchor tags look like for you. Chances are though, if you don't already know that, you probably can't answer my question anyway.

Comment: @BVernon , stop arguing and being rude! We are here to help you and you  are not supposed to behave like that !

Comment: Hey, I was just responding in like manner. You want people to be nice to you; be nice to them.

Comment: @BVernon this was your problem , why do you find it necessary to insult others ?? Spirit of this site is to help those that are willing to accept help

Comment: @charlietfl Within about 30 seconds of posting my question I had 4 downvotes, one person yelling at me that there is no code, and another one rhetorically pointing out that there are no anchor tags in my post. How I form my anchor tags are COMPLETELY unnecessary to know for answering this question. You guys are ridiculous... you heckle people and then you're upset when they aren't grateful for your nonsense.

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com No, you didn't help me. gibberish helped me, but don't say "we" because you didn't help me at all. You only heckled me for not providing a totally irrelevant fragment of information.

Comment: seek counseling BVernon. You posted a question that showed no attempt at researching the topic. Why wouldn't you expect downvotes and requests for clarification

Comment: @charlietfl Why are you wasting your time responding now? Is it because you want to help me; or is it because you like policing the site and arguing with people who talk back to you? Go bother someone else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are talking about is sometimes called `scroll spy`

Here is a jsFiddle (written by an unknown SO hero) that shows a simplified example.

http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/up4nu/

Basically, you use the `$(window).scroll()` function to keep tabs on where the user is in the document.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
   // Get container scroll position
   var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop()+topMenuHeight;

   // Get id of current scroll item
   var cur = scrollItems.map(function(){
     if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop)
       return this;
   });

});
```